# How can i try to read to topic in kafka when i am getting an error as Missing required argument "[topic]"

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am getting an error while reading a topic from a single node cluster

```
kafka-console-producer.bat -- broker-list localhost:9092 -- topic raja
```

Error below

```
Missing required argument "[topic]"
```

kafka version-kafka_2.13-2.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you do more research and training.

You use kafka CONSUMER to read from a topic, NOT PRODUCER,
and also, as @Robin Moffatt mentioned while I was typing the answer,
remove spaces between the parameter labels:

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic raja
```

This should work.

If you want to read the topic from the beginning then add this as well:

```
--from-beginning
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a space between the parameter labels, so it won't work. Also note `consumer` not `producer` if you're reading from the topic.

Try:

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic raja
```

Ref: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_consume